# PHP's session_start() conflicting with error_reporting()?

Tags: php, class, session, error-handling

When I was going over error handling in php's manual, someone posted an interesting comment regarding a possible conflict. Here's the link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php.

Basically, it stated that calling session_start() before error_reporting() would cause error_reporting() to behave incorrectly. Instead, the order would have to be flipped. I was curious of anyone experienced this issue before.

More importantly, though, if there is an issue, how will that affect classes? For instance, if I were to implement a class - such as user login - with it's own specific error handling system involving error_reporting(), would there be a conflict? To be more specific, if I had a file with session_start() then I call the class like I stated above.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I do not know about this issue and I also do not trust any of the comments on PHP.net (sadly). Can you describe the incorrect behavior and provide a test scenario? Ensuring a call to `error_reporting` before `session_start` without entangling would be ungodly.

Comment: I don't trust them either. And that was what I was curious about, because I've personally haven't seen an issue. Especially when you consider designing a class and having it's own error handling system. I would find it hard to accept there is really an issue.

Comment: Do you set different error reporting levels for each class? And if so, why?

Comment: Seriously, I can't think of a valid reason to do that. Usually you would either show them all in development or hide them all in production.

Comment: No, I don't affect the levels in each class - it would be pointless and cumbersome. But in the case of an extraordinary situation, I thought it would be useful to know. I just found the comment in the manual rather odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the two functions are obviously completely unrelated.

Second, I've called `error_reporting` both before and after `session_start` and never witnessed a problem.  No one who uses my framework has reporting any issues either.  It's best to set `error_reporting` once near the start of the application, but sometimes I'll set it at a deeper level when debugging a specific section of other people's code.

However, if you were to output errors (display errors on) before starting the session, you can get header warnings if you're not output buffering.

Comment: True, those header warnings are probably what the commenter at php.net experienced somehow.

Answer (score 1):

While not directly answering your question, but using `ob_start()` as the very first call would most likely solve your problems here as headers and content order would no longer matter when output buffering is on.